# Why is arraylist loop crashing on removing elements

Tags: java, arraylist, crash

I'm trying to print all the elements of an arraylist and remove them from the array at the same time using the following code.

```
while(!duplicates.isEmpty()){
outpurWriter.println(duplicates.remove(0));
}
```

It works when the arraylist is small in size but if the arraylist contains say 400000 elements it crashes after the first few thousand.

I've changed my code around to just use a for loop to print each element then set the arraylist = null, but just wondering what is wrong with the code I used originally.

Cheers

Comment: How does it "crash"? Do you have a stacktrace, perhaps?

Comment: Also, note that this is a very expensive way of working. If you don't mind the order in which it removes items, it would be *much* cheaper to remove the last item on each iteration.

Comment: It would certainly be more efficient to loop for printing THEN clear the list.

Comment: Are you sure the "ArrayList" is the issue and not the output stream?

Comment: For such iterations a `LinkedList` is far better. If ou use the `List` only for this iteration try using a `LinkedList`.

Comment: By "crash" you mean that the iteration stop working or finish the iteration after removing an item from this list, right?

Comment: What "type" are you storing in an arraylist? any traces?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<String> listString = new ArrayList<String>();
        listString.add("a");
        listString.add("b");
        listString.add("c");
        listString.add("d");

        System.out.println("Size of arraylist before remove: "+listString.size());
        ListIterator<String> listIterator = listString.listIterator();
        while (listIterator.hasNext())
        {
            listIterator.next();
            listIterator.remove();
        }
        System.out.println("Size of arraylist after remove: "+listString.size());
    }
```

If you have requirement where you have more insert and delete operations, please use linkedlist